# Proving existence of an element of trace 1

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, trace

Let $F=\mathbb{F}_{q}$ be a finite field of order $q=2^{n}$ and let $\beta$ be a primitive element of $F$. I would like to prove that if $q>4$, then for each $1\leq i \leq \frac{q-2}{2}$, there exists a $1\leq j \leq \frac{q-2}{2}$ such that $j \neq i$ and
$$Tr\left(\frac{\beta^{i+j}}{1+\beta^{2i}}\right)=1,$$
where $Tr: F\to \mathbb{F}_{2}$ is the trace map.

I have checked using a computer that this is true for $q$ up to $128$, however I am not sure how to proceed with proving such a statement.

Could anyone give any hints?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$. Then we know that $m(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+1$. Furthermore, because $m(1)\neq0$ we also know that $m(x)$ has an odd number of non-zero terms. Denote by $S$ the set of indices $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n$ such that the term $x^k$ appears in $m(x)$ with coefficient $1$. In other words
$$
m(x)=\sum_{k\in S}x^k.
$$

For all sufficiently large $n$ the allowed range of exponents $j$ has a run of length $n$ such that $i$ is not in that range. Let $[\ell,\ell+n-1]$ be such a run. Let us denote
$$b(j)=Tr\big(\frac{\beta^{i+j}}{1+\beta^{2i}}\big).$$
I claim that there exists at least one $j, \ell\le j<\ell+n$ such that
$b(j)=1$.

Assume contrariwise that $b(j)=0$ for all $j\in[\ell,\ell+n-1]$. The key is that
for any exponent $t$ we have the recurrence relation
$$
\sum_{k\in S}b(t+k)=0. \qquad(*)
$$
This is because
$$
\sum_{k\in S}b(t+k)=\sum_{k\in S}Tr\big(\frac{\beta^{i+t+k}}{1+\beta^{2i}}\big)=
Tr\big(\frac{\beta^{i+t}}{1+\beta^{2i}}m(\beta)\big)=Tr(0)=0.
$$
Recall that $0$ and $n$ are both in the set $S$. Our contrapositive assumption and the equation $(*)$ applied to $t=\ell$ imply that $b(\ell+n)=0$ also. Applying $(*)$ to $t=\ell+1$ then implies that $b(\ell+n+1)=0$, too. Continuing in this way we see that together with the contrapositive assumption equation $(*)$ implies that $b(j')=0$ for all $j'\ge\ell$ up to $j'=\ell+q-2$. But, because $\beta^i/(1+\beta^{2i})\neq0$ this implies that the trace vanishes on all of $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}^*$. This is known not to be the case.

---

The so called *linear complexity* (=depth of the shortest recurrence relation) of your sequence is $n$, and a general fact of sequences generated by such a recurrence relation is that they cannot have a run of $n$ zeros unless the entire sequence consists of zeros.

Comment: The argument seems to only show the existence of an element of trace $0$. I can't seem to understand why that would imply the existence of an element of trace $1$? Also, should the exponent of $x$ in the summation for $m(x)$ be $k$ instead of $s$?

Comment: @Ishika: Indeed, I had totally misread the question. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Could you explain what it means by a run of length $n$?

Comment: Sorry, that is coding theory/sequence parlance. A run of length $n$ is a subsequence of $n$ identical bits. So a run of $n$ zeros together with a recurrence relation of depth $n$ means that the sequence will continue as zeros only.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't seem to understand - if $[l,l+n-1]$ is a subsequence of $[1,\frac{q-2}{2}]$, then how can $l$ possibly be negative?  I don't think I understand how the interval $[l,l+n-1]$ is being defined.

Comment: Yeah. Ok. If $i>n+1$ we can let $\ell=1$ otherwise let $\ell=i+1$. The point is that if the trace vanishes for $n$ consecutive values of $j$ it vanishes for all $j$ (even outside your range), which is not possible.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the argument now, except for the very last assertion. How does showing that $b(j')=0$, for all $j'\geq l$ show that the trace vanishes on the whole of $F^{*}$? I have tried the following. If I take $\gamma\in F^{*}$, then I can write $\gamma=\frac{\beta^{i+j'}}{1+\beta^{2i}}$, for some $j'\geq 0$, so $Tr(\gamma)=b(j')$ but this is only known to be $0$ if $j'\geq l$. Do we know that $j'\geq l$ or is there a different argument for this?

Comment: Also we are not actually using the fact that $S$ has an order number of terms, are we? And the first time $b(j)$ is defined in your solution it says $b(j)=Tr(...)=0$ - it shouldn't equal $0$ right?

Comment: 1) The result applies to all $j'$ in the range $\ell\le j'<\ell+q-1$ (and beyond, but that's not needed). 2) Yes. That was another copy/paste error from the earlier version. Sorry, @Ishika :-)

Comment: Many thanks! Just one last thing I noticed. You claim that there exists at least one $j$ such that $l\leq j\leq l+n$ and $b(j)=1$ - should that be $l\leq j \leq l+n-1$?

Comment: @Ishika: The variables are integers, so $j<\ell+n$ if and only if $j\le\ell+n-1$.

Comment: Yes - Sorry I just misread the inequality!